# Can the SQLite libraries for C#.NET be used for Windows Phone 8 app development?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8

I've spent hours reading on different SQLite libraries and wrappers available for the C#.NET and Windows Phone 8 platform and I feel a bit overwhelmed and confused.

My questions are 1. can the SQLite libraries for C#.NET be used for Windows Phone 8 app development? and 2. How do I decide which library or wrapper will be best suitable for my project?

Comment: any reason to not use the one in the local storage? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202860(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: sqlite has native support in wp8. There is a [C++/CX wrapper](https://github.com/peterhuene/sqlite-net-wp8) that is intended to be used with [sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net). So if you want to use SQLite in your WP8 projects then read the instructions in [sqlite-net-wp8](https://github.com/peterhuene/sqlite-net-wp8) project page

Comment: As per anything, you have to find the one that targets the correct platform.  In this case, WP8.  If the library does not say it targets WP8, it probably doesn't.

Comment: @Will true that. But as WP8 apps can be written using C#, I wanted to verify whether SQLite libraries that target C# also target WP8.

Comment: @gabriel I'll explore your option.

Comment: @AlaaMasoud can you please point me to a good article that teaches how to use this wrapper? Thanks.

Comment: @NiiLaryea: We don't do links.

Answer (score 0):

Go thorough bellow link

[Windows Phone 7 Native Database Programming via Sqlite Client for Windows Phone](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/Windows-Phone-7-Native-Database-Programming-via-Sqlite-Client-for-Windows-Phone.aspx)

[SQLite-WinRT: Database programming on Windows Phone and Windows 8](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andy_wigley/archive/2013/06/06/sqlite-winrt-database-programming-on-windows-phone-and-windows-8.aspx)

[How to use SQLite in Windows Phone](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_SQLite_in_Windows_Phone)

Hope it will help you